# Recursive lookup: linking a field to the same table in MS Access

Tags: microsoft-access, tasks, to-do, tree-view

I know it's abhorrent database design, but I'm experimenting to see if I can achieve unlimited hierarchy for a custom tasks manager in MS Access.

I managed to make this by using a lookup to the same table...

[image: Recursive lookup]

...however after refreshing it returns to looking like this:

[image: recursion view lost]

All I'm interested in is this tree view, whether it be a table, query, report or form.

Any suggestions?

*I am aware of the multitude of software out there that achieve similar functionality. However the reason I prefer Access is so that I can extend it and customise it completely to my needs.*

Comment: 'vote to close' taggers, please state the criticism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally users should be modifying data in Forms not in a table-view.  You can certainly build a relationship for a table to point at itself.  But having the tables actually provide the view you want is almost certainly not going to work.

Comment: Good to know I point at self relationship is okay! The user will just be me, but you're right: table-view was never really designed to be the front end! But what in a form can show objects in a tree?